# MySQL query to display one record before today's date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I can't find an answer to my question, it's probably easy but... anyway!

I have a database with every NHL game for one specific team in a table.  Every game has been entered in the good order.

On my home page, I would like to display the upcoming game as well as the result of the previous game.  How can I create a mySQL query to display the previous game based on today's date?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you at least show us your table structure?

Comment: Sure, so I have these columns set in the table "games": GameNo, Away, Home, AwayScore, HomeScore, GameDate, GameTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your game records have a timestamp or datetime value?

If so you could write a query ordering your games by the date smaller that now() and limit by one.

The query should look like this:

```
select * from games where gamedate < now() order by gamedate desc limit 1
```

Comment: Yep the game date is included for each of them. Could you update your answer with the code please?